# Database-like search algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, search

I have a collection of objects. Each object is described by ~4 parameters (let's say two integers and two strings). How can I implement this collection in C++ to be able to quickly find subsets of these objects by specifying search-criterias, i.e. "find all object with first parameter equal to 1", or "search all objects with second parameter equal to 'foo' " (lookup is always performed using one-parameter query: `parameter=value`). Should I have 4 `std::maps`, so that each parameter based lookup is performed in `O(logn)` ? What if I add another parameter and another?

Are there any existing solutions for this problem?

Comment: Why not use an actual database? SQLite or something similar? Does that not fit your requirements?

Comment: Will it always be equals comparisons or will you want to do inequalities and whatnot?

Comment: @Corbin: always equals comparisions

Comment: @Bart: I am unable to use any existing db-engine. I must introduce a simple solution

Comment: How large of dataset?  Will it always feasibly fit in memory?  Also, I have a feeling that this should be tagged homework (maybe not?).

Comment: @Corbin: Let's say 1000 objects, not much but lookup is performed very often, so linear solution is too slow.

Comment: I'd use [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/) + standard library algorithms (`std::find_if`, etc.).

Comment: I would probably just use hash tables then.  Probably would not fit future requirements, but for now would be a very quick and easy implementation.  Edit: Didn't know Boost had MultiIndex.  Probably better to go that route than bare maps :).

Comment: You asked for existing solutions, but the most obvious existing solution, a database, is something you say you are "unable to use." Can you please be more specific about what your actual requirements are so that people don't waste their time coming up with other ideas you'll have to reject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [Boost Multi Index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/), which is meant for just this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

One array for the data, four hash tables (`std::tr1::unordered_map`) for the indexes.

Comment: [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/) will wrap that up into a single container for you. ;-]